# How does a level set look like when the minimum point of a function degenerate?

Tags: differential-topology, morse-theory

I apologize in advance if this question is well-known. I would like to know an explicit example of a compact, connected manifold $M$ and a smooth function $f: M \to\mathbb{R}$ which satisfy the following properties (1)-(3):

(1) We denote by m the minimum value of $f$. Then there is an unique point $p$ on $M$ such that $f(p)=m$.

(2) By (1), $p$ is a critical point of $f$. We assume that $p$ is an isolated critical point. But we also assume that $p$ is a *degenerate* critical point.

(3) Let $c$ be a real number which is slightly bigger than $m$. Then the level set $f^{-1}(c)$ is not homeomorphic to a sphere.

Note: If $p$ is a non-degenerate critical point, then Morse lemma shows that $f^{-1}(c)$ is a sphere.

Another question: If a function $f: M \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfies the above (1) and (2), then can we conclude that $f^{-1}(c)$ is a homological sphere?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1231047/how-level-sets-look-like-when-a-critical-point-degenerate